# Word-usage "That which" (used togheter) or only "which"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

I have seen in a game this statement:

> Shinning as lucifer, the morning star in the dawn, showing a beauty that is not God's. — **That which** appears within grasp.

Could I say only which ("which appears within grasp")?

I've researched about the meaning of "that which" and it turns out "that which" refers to a noun phrase (in this context, it would be "The morning star"), and, sometimes, being a *wordy* word to say "what/whatever" E.g "That which doesn't kill us, it just makes us stronger".

And even sometimes I see stranges uses of "which" itself (e.g  This word means 'To express the extent to *which* you'd never be on something')

Could you guys help? Correct if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Including the word ***that*** is a (poor, imho) stylistic choice in your "Lucifer" context. Just ignore it, and don't *copy* the usage. And native speakers wouldn't usually say *That which doesn't kill us, it just makes us stronger* precisely because it's "wordy". We usually say ***Anything that / What / Whatever** doesn't kill me just makes me stronger*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shinning as lucifer, the morning star in the dawn, showing a beauty
>   that is not God's. — ***That which*** appears within grasp.

Could I say only which ("which appears within grasp")?

**Yes, you can!**

**"That"** here is a stylish directive to the morning star being within the grasp.

**THAT**

Used to refer to a person, object, idea, etc. that is separated from the speaker by space or time:

> I've never liked that cousin of hers.
>
> Who's that? Is that the girl you told me about?
>
> How much are those shoes?
>
> His handwriting is like that (= the writing) of a much younger child.

or in your context it is used to refer to something that has been mentioned or was involved earlier, or to something that is already known about:

> Where's that pen (= the one I was using earlier) gone?
>
> She lives in that house at the end of Jeremy's street (= you know which one I mean).

**To be exact in the meaning:**

> **That which appears within grasp:**  The one item you know is within grasp.
>
> **Which appears within grasp:** The item is within grasp.